# What is "Gateway Host Probe"?

Tags: network, metasploit

I wanted to perform Stress Testing on my router using Metasploit to perform a **TCP syn Denial Of Service** attack.
I have used the following commands:

```
use auxiliary/dos/tcp/synflood
```

`set rhost 192.168.65.204`  **(this is  my routers ip)**

```
show options
```

it showed this :

```
 Name       Current Setting  Required  Description


 ----       ---------------  --------  -----------
   INTERFACE                   no        The name of the interface
   NUM                         no        Number of SYNs to send (else unlimited)
   RHOST      192.168.65.204   yes       The target address
   RPORT      80               yes       The target port
   SHOST                       no        The spoofable source address (else randomizes)
   SNAPLEN    65535            yes       The number of bytes to capture
   SPORT                       no        The source port (else randomizes)
   TIMEOUT    500              yes       The number of seconds to wait for new data
```

And when i executed `run` command the following error occurred:

```
[-] Auxiliary failed: Msf::OptionValidateError The following options failed to validate: GATEWAY_PROBE_HOST.
```

Can anyone please explain what does it mean and how to fix this error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default value of `$GATEWAY_PROBE_HOST` is 8.8.8.8, which the module initially contacts with a TTL value of 1. This is done to discover the current default gateway (since TTL will expire at the default gateway and it will send an [ICMP time exceeded message](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Control_Message_Protocol#Time_exceeded)). It seems like you have an invalid IP address in the GATEWAY_PROBE_HOST datastore option. Run the command in the terminal:

```
msfconsole
use auxiliary/dos/tcp/synflood
show advanced
```

and look at the configured value. To set it to 8.8.8.8 or any other external or internal host, use the set command. Further run

```
set GATEWAY_PROBE_HOST 8.8.8.8
```

Configure the required datastore options and run again.

Answer (score -1):

Your `INTERFACE` field is empty! You have to set it to the interface from which the packets will be sent.

Also it is a good idea to first ping the remote machine to check if it is alive.

To find list of interfaces on Linux machine. Use `ifconfig -a` command.

To find list of interfaces on a Windows machine. Use `netsh interface show interface` command.

Comment: That field is optional. And I have tried to execute it with interface eth0, then also same error occurred

Comment: Can you ping the router?

Comment: yes i am able to ping the router

Comment: @Hunter Are you able to perform any other exploits? Just to make sure that metasploit is working fine. This exploit is working for me. Could be a problem with your copy of metasploit.